# ElasticSearch: Facets from child documents

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I have two documents in **parent - child** relationship and I want to get the **number** and also the **max value** of a **date** field from the children documents **grouped** by the value of the parent id. In other words, for every parent document I want to count its children and get its latest child. In addition, it would be great if the date field would have the same format and not be returned as a timestamp value.

I already tried more facets, but nothing seems to return the desired answer. Could anyone provide some insights about how to achieve this? Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you should look and play around with http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-stats-facet.html
value field will be date
key field will be _parent

I suppose, it should return max, min, count, etc. (read docs) for each _parent, but you must play with it

Comment: btw, with new aggregation framework this should be easier to calculate https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3300. Though it's now in beta2 stage